# PHP showing up as a text instead of the application

Tags: php

So I am new to coding PHP and am working on creating a login system. I have followed this tutorial and have done everything that he has said, but when I open any of the files it just shows the code. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk

I really need help figuring this out and would love any feedback that I can get.

Here is the code that I used for index.php

```
    <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Session:exists('home')) {
    echo '<p>'. Session::flash('home') . '<p>';
}

$user = new User();
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
?>
    <p> Hello <a href="#"><?php echo escape(user->data()->username);</a>!</p>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php"> Log out</a></li>
    </ul>

<?php
} else {
    echo '<p> You need to <a href="login.php">log in</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: usually means your server isnt setup properly to execute php scripts.

Comment: is your extension .php or .html? did you touch the .htaccess file or other PHP configurations? also - are you running it on local host or server?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Sound like you might not have XAMPP for windows/mac or php for linux installed

Comment: So I am not sure if my hosting server is currently set up to execute php scripts and I am not sure how to go about finding that out. I am using godaddy hosting and right now all i did was change the file name from index.html to index.php

Comment: @yani I am using a godaddy hosting server, and I have not changed the .htaccess file or any of the PHP configurations

Comment: call their support, they'll know...

Comment: @Yani call them and say what thought, I am still not even sure what is wrong, whether it is the code itself or a actual server error.

Comment: @StephenCorcoran Do I need to install this on the server, and how would I do that exactly? Thanks so much

Comment: Make a new script that does `<?php echo "hello world";?>`. if it doesn't run then you have a server configuration problem. If it does run, the problem is on your script.

Comment: @Yani yes it does work, so does that mean it is strictly the script that is wrong? If so, do you see any errors in my index file? Thanks so much for all the help

Comment: What is the file extension for your index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that PHP is running correctly and the error is in the main file or the included file.

Try the following:

1. Make sure your included file `core/init.php` has `<?php` opening and `?>` closing tags.
2. When using `include` or `require`, the included file must not contain white spaces or line breaks before the opening tag. Make sure that `init.php` does not contain any white spaces or line breaks before the opening `<?php` tag.
3. You forgot to close the php tag on line 9 of the sampled code:

   change: `<p> Hello <a href="#"><?php echo escape(user->data()->username);</a>!</p>`
   to:`<p> Hello <a href="#"><?php echo escape(user->data()->username);?></a>!</p>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: You'd also want to change `Session:exists` to `Session::exists` on line 4 and `user->data()->username` to `$user->data()->username` on line 11.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you just double clicked the php file and opened it in browser so the address bar looks something like: file://xyz/path/to_your/file.php
If that's the case, put http://**localhost**/path/to_your/file.php